# Can I dump unwanted compounds?

Tags: spacechem

In Spacechem, can I release or dump unwanted compounds without using pipelines to store them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some stages have **Recyclers**. Any compounds that get sent to these are destroyed.

[image: Recycler]

There are also **Storage Tanks**, which serve as a temporary buffer for compounds. They basically act like a 25-square-long pipe.

[image: Storage tank]